# Under loop, how to assign event depending on the condition based on index value

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a loop of 50 divs, in which I am assigning event based on the current element. However I want to assign event based on a condition.

For example, divs are arranged one behind another, just like a photo stack.
I want user to first hit first div, then only they should able to hit second div then third div and so on till they reach the end of divs.

Because of the below code user can hit on any of the div and perform action. But action needs to be performed one by one. One div after another. Please suggest the solution.

```
var flag=0;
var flipImage=document.querySelectorAll('.shadow');  
   for(j=0; j<flipImage.length; j++){
   var currentFlipImage=flipImage[j];
      if(j==flag){
      flag++; 
      currentFlipImage.addEventListener('click',flipDown,false);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
var _handler = null;
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.shadow');
var length = images.length;

function attachHandler(index) {
    if(_handler) {
        // remove the click handler from the previous image
        images[index-1].removeEventListener('click', _handler, false);
        _handler = null;
    }
    if(index < length) {
        var handler = function(event) {
            flipDown(event);
            attachHandler(index+1); // add the click handler to next image
        }
        images[index].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
        _handler = handler;  // capture reference for removal
    }
}

attachHandler(0);
```

This only generates and adds event listeners when needed.

Important side note: The return value of `querySelectorAll()` is a `NodeList` which is *live*. That means any time you call `length` on this object, the list is reevaluated (the elements are searched again) which adds a performance overhead. Thus, never use `list.length` in the `for` loop. Capture the `length` beforehand.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rM3C7/)

If you want to make it going in a loop, just remove the `if` statement (keep the body of course) and do

```
index = index % length;
```

Comment: This solution looks perfect. However on every current div i need to attached a class called flip down, which allow the div to flipdown. When i am trying i am getting very strange animation. below code i have in flipdown function.                                       var obj=event.target; obj.className='flipDown';                    i think, class is getting assign to mousevent, instead of actual div. What is the solution for it??

Comment: @user504023: Could you create a jsFiddle with your code? It is difficult to help with this information only, but it looks like you are attaching the class in the correct way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually i got solution to handle this. I am using event.currentTarget, instead of event.target. This is working fine now. Your above code really help me alot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each div a sequential ID then adding the click event to the next in sequence

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function div_click(event)
{
  var div_clicked = event.currentTarget,
      next_sequence = parseInt(div_clicked.id.split("_")[1]) + 1,
      next_div = document.getElementById("mydiv_" + next_sequence);
  //alerts are just for testing here
  alert(div_clicked.id);
  alert(next_div.id);

  div_clicked.removeEventListener('click',div_click,false);
  next_div.addEventListener('click',div_click,false);
}

window.onload = function()
{
  var first_div = document.getElementById("mydiv_0");
  first_div.addEventListener('click',div_click,false);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv_0">Click 0</div>
<div id="mydiv_1">Click 1</div>
<div id="mydiv_2">Click 2</div>
<div id="mydiv_3">Click 3</div>
<div id="mydiv_4">Click 4</div>
<div id="mydiv_5">Click 5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Worth a shot?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var flipImage = document.querySelectorAll('.shadow'), current = 0;
function flipDown(){
   current++;
   current = (current > flipImage.length)? 0 : current;
   for(j = 0; j < flipImage.length; j++){
      flipImage[j].style.zIndex = (j == current)? 2 : 1;
   }
}
window.onload = function(){
  for(j = 0; j < flipImage.length; j++){
    flipImage[j].onmouseclick=flipDown;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. Yes, the effects will be executed in order of the divs, but it does not matter on which div one clicks.

Comment: You are right, but it *should* work if the divs are placed on top of each other. I totally agree your answer fits the OP's question better

Comment: Ah, sorry JCOC611, I forgot about the position. You are right, then it does not matter ;) Nevermind!

Answer (score 0):

When you have an arbitrary number of elements that share the same event handler, handling all the events from a common parent is usually better than assigning handlers to each element.

This doesnt work for 'focus' or non-bubbling events, but it is useful for touch, mouse and keyboard events.

It is usually easier to coordinate actions based on conditions from a constant 'switchboard' handler than from arbitrary elements.